# Is there a Minecraft mod that acts like an autoclicker that works even when I switch to a different window?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Normally, when I need to use an autoclicker to do things in Minecraft, I have to keep the Minecraft window open, and I can't switch over to a different window to do something else. Is there a Minecraft mod or some other application that keeps clicking for me in Minecraft 1.16.5 even when I switch to a different window?

Comment: Wouldn't Minecraft pause anyway when you switch windows/applications?

Comment: There's an option called "Pause when lost focus" which you can turn off, so it doesn't pause when you tab out.

Comment: Does Baritone count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an autoclicker I have here (though not mine). So when you click on the link you  are now in github, a code sharing forum, and click download code. The instuctions are also in there but here is it in case it changes:

Minecraft Auto Clicker

Be sure to go into options.txt in your .minecraft folder and set "pauseOnLostFocus" to "false"
Must be done with Minecraft closed
To access your .minecraft folder, open explorer and paste this into the address bar:

%appdata%.minecraft
Alternatively, you can also do F3 + P in game until it says "Pause on lost focus: disabled"

To Use:

Line yourself up for whatever action you want to take and then bring up the menu. Go into the application and click "Start".

Once you click start, you will have 3 seconds to go into the game and exit the menu. When the countdown hits 0, the program will run and will auto tab you out of the game.

When you want to stop, click "Stop" and it will stop the action.

Here is the link and happy grinding!

https://github.com/smith-j-travis/MinecraftAutoClicker

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any auto clicker mod but I know about an application I use as my auto clicker.
You don't need to install anything.
Just download OP Auto Clicker from the link below and you can auto click.
Link: https://www.opautoclicker.com/